# merge batch and automation tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

Should [batch](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch) be merged into [automation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation)?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that they're the same.

Automation can be, for example, something like an Photoshop action recording which automates something like the steps for high pass sharpening or frequency separation. This automates those processes, but not necessarily in batch.

Batch, to me anyway, is about applying some consistent change to a volume of images. While that's a form of automation, the automation model usually seems to have a connotation of something that can be used again while a batch feels like a one-off.

At any rate, I think I would leave them alone.

Comment: I agree, I think they are different tags.